# Names for equations that do and don't explicitly include units in them?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, unit-of-measure

I realize the question is vague; my question is actually how to clarify it.  Is there any terminology distinguishing the two types or styles of equations in these examples?

Ex. 1.  The following equation gives the distance $x$ in meters using the time $t$ in seconds:
$x = 3t$.  Find $x$ after 5 seconds goes by.

Ex. 2.  The following equation gives the distance $x$ using the time $t$:
$x = (3m/s)t$.  Find $x$ after 5 seconds goes by.

I teach high school physics and would like to convince students to use the 2nd style, which seems more easily generalizable, but they learn the 1st style in their math classes.

Comment: What do you mean by "more easily generalizable"?